# Simular eventos de teclas em javascript

Tags: javascript, eventos

Estou à procura de uma maneira de simular o `keypress` de `shift + 1` via javascript para criar um ponto de exclamação `!` para uma série de testes (specs) numa framework em que estou envolvido.

Tenho usado uma framework (Syn) [, **exemplo de jsFiddle**,](http://jsfiddle.net/RefeY/) mas não consigo atravéz dela reproduzir/disparar o evento de um keypress `shift + 1`.

[Segundo a documentação](http://bitovi.com/blog/2010/07/syn-a-standalone-synthetic-event-library.html) seria:

```
Syn.type('JavaScriptMVC[shift]1[shift-up]', 'elementID')
```

Mas não tive sucesso em conseguir detectar o `.shiftKey == true` no evento.

**Existe outra maneira usando javascript "puro" ?**

Tentei usar [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12187302/2256325) no SO sem sucesso e percebí que o `createEvent` está deprecado e não encontrei também outro caminho.

Comment: O teste tem que ser necessariamente escrito em javascript... senão poderia usar alguma ferramenta de automação do browser, como o [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: Ou então o [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/)... que permite escrever scripts em javascript para manipular o browser, que é um webkit headless.

Comment: Porque não utiliza o Jquery e com ele você faz um evento trigger?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver essa questão Sergio?

Comment: @durtto sim e não. Para browsers modernos o Syn funciona. Para IE<8 não.

Comment: Estou nessa situação(pouco parecida) e estou em busca do melhor código. Sobre IE<8 não tenho preocupação pois eu dito qual browser usar.

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz um pequeno script, acredito que não seja a solução, mas acredito que possa te levar a uma.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
<input type="text" id="kinput" style="font-size:150%;width:600px">
<br>
<textarea style="width:600px;border:1px solid black" onfocus="this.blur()" id="textArea" rows="18"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="reset" value="Limpar" />
</form> 
    <script>
        document.getElementById('kinput').onkeydown = khandle
        document.getElementById('kinput').onkeyup = khandle
        document.getElementById('kinput').onkeypress = khandle
        function khandle(e) {
          e = e || event;
          var evt = e.type;
          while (evt.length < 10) evt += ' '
          showmesg(evt + 
            ' keyCode=' + e.keyCode + 
            ' which=' + e.which + 
            ' charCode=' + e.charCode +
            ' char=' + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.charCode) +
            (e.shiftKey ? ' +shift' : '') +
            (e.ctrlKey ? ' +ctrl' : '') +
            (e.altKey ? ' +alt' : '') +
            (e.metaKey ? ' +meta' : ''), 'key'
          )

        }
        function showmesg(t, form) {
            var area = document.getElementById('textArea');
            area.value += t + '\n';
            area.scrollTop = area.scrollHeight
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bruno, obrigado por ter visto a minha pergunta. Na verdade o que eu procuro não é analizar o evento nem as propriedades do objeto evento. O que eu quero é simular/criar/despoletar um evento que insira texto no meu input programáticamente. Se achou a pergunta pouco clara lamento e esteja à vontade para sugerir alterações. Dê uma olhada ao __jsFiddle__ que coloquei na pergunta e talvez isso ajude a clarificar. Obrigado.

Comment: Amigo, talvez voce consiga usando o VBScript no InternetExplorer numa configuração de baixa segurança. Através do VBScript voce pode acessar o objeto do seu navegador e simular um click ou keypress...

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma lib bacana para trabalhar com hotkeys [jquery.hotkeys](https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys)

Atualizei o fiddle, da uma olhada http://jsfiddle.net/RefeY/1/